# provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a function that return all data from a table. I am using Ado.Net with c# when I am calling the function it shows this error.
`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)`
I checked the configuration setting every thing is enable.

### Image

[image]